# Transferir dados de um input hidden para uma rota

Tags: laravel-5.6

Eu tenho a função score de um controle com o seguinte código :

`public function score($ids, $points) {
$score = Team::find($ids)->increment('points', $points) ;`

O campo $ids vai receber vários id's que estou gravando em um input do tipo hidden. A ideia é pegar as id e incrementar a pontuação dos que estão no input. Por exemplo nele terá 3,4,6,10. Eu carrego de outro controller os pontos, bastando declarar $quest->points. Como faço pra passar esses dois parâmetros usando um button?

Comment: Você está passando isso de um form? Já tentou colocar o button com tipo submit?

Comment: Eu estou tentando passar sem usar form. Quero usar assim: `{{route('team.score',input_ids,$question->points)}}`. Esse input_ids é o input hidden com as id's que serão incrementadas

Comment: Está usando algo mais? Tipo o um jquery?

Comment: Exatamente. Como faço isso via jquery?

Comment: Então converta o button em a href e adicione a classe btn e os atributos `data-id=$id` e `data-question=$points` a partir daí dá para você fazer o envio com ajax